# C# Login Form InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, authentication, connection, invalidoperationexception

I have 3 type of account: Administrator, Staff and Student. When I login the Administrator user the code is okey, then the problem occur when I try to login Student user and Staff user.

```
Type:Administrator
Username:admin
Password:1234

Type:Student
Username:14-2022703
Password:lastname

Type:Staff
Username:staff
Password:2535
```

My Code:

```
namespace WindowsTest
{
    public partial class LogIn : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=dbEnroll;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;
        public LogIn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = txtUsername.Text;
            string password = txtPassword.Text;
            if (getData(username, password).Equals(true))
            {
                if (getType(username, password).Equals("Administrator"))
                {
                    Enrollment enroll = new Enrollment();
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Log In", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                    enroll.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else if (getType(username, password).Equals("Staff"))
                {
                    Enrollment enroll = new Enrollment();
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Log In", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                    enroll.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else if (getType(username, password).Equals("Student"))
                {
                    Subject sub = new Subject();
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Log In", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                    sub.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtUsername.Clear();
                txtPassword.Clear();
                txtUsername.Focus();
            }
        }

        private bool getData(string username, string password)
        {
            con.Open();
            string sql = "select*from tblAccount where Username='" + username + "' and Password='" + password + "'";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private string getType(string username, string password)
        {
            con.Open(); //InvalidOperationException
            string sql = "select Type from tblAccount where Username='" + username + "' and Password='" + password + "'";
            cmd=new SqlCommand(sql,con);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            return dr[0].ToString();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of the exception to the question? And for inner exceptions, if there are any.

Comment: InvalidOperationException was unhandled = The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

That what the error said.

Comment: And the stack trace was...

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statements for staff and student check against `getData` while you probably meant `getType`.

Other than that, please read a good tutorial on `IDisposable` and `using` blocks.

Comment: I change getData to getType from my if-statement but still the error are still there.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of for you getting this error is the connection already being opened.

You should trust the connection pooling infrastructure to manage connections and scope any connection objects to its usage.

You should also consider using the [connection strings configuration element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms254494.aspx) to make your connection string configurable.

You should also consider using parameters with your commands to avoid SQL injection attacks.

```
private string GetUserType(string username, string password)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"]))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Type from tblAccount where Username = @Username and Password = @Password", con))
        {
            cmd.AddParameter("@Username", username);
            cmd.AddParameter("@Password", password);

            con.Open();

            using (SqlReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                return (dr.Read()) ? dr[0] as string : return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your code using this method is also unnecessarily hitting the database too many times. Consider changing to something like this:

```
switch (GetUserType(username, password).Equals(true))
{
    case "Administrator":
        Enrollment enroll = new Enrollment();
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Log In", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        enroll.Show();
        this.Hide();
        break;
    case "Staff":
        Enrollment enroll = new Enrollment();
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Log In", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        enroll.Show();
        this.Hide();
        break;
    case "Student":
        Subject sub = new Subject();
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Log In", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        sub.Show();
        this.Hide();
        break;
    default:
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        txtUsername.Clear();
        txtPassword.Clear();
        txtUsername.Focus();
        break;
}
```

Or, if you need some control over the comparison:

```
string userType = GetUserType(username, password);
if (userType.Equals("Administrator", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Enrollment enroll = new Enrollment();
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Log In", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    enroll.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
else if (userType.Equals("Staff", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Enrollment enroll = new Enrollment();
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Log In", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    enroll.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
else if (userType.Equals("Student", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Subject sub = new Subject();
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Log In", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    sub.Show();
    this.Hide();
} else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    txtUsername.Clear();
    txtPassword.Clear();
    txtUsername.Focus();
}
```

This code is strill overly complex. You should consider removing all non UI code to a separate class and return just a boolean or an enum and do your UI based on it's response:

```
public class Users
{
    public string GetUserType(string username, string password)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public partial class LogIn : Form
{
    private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User user = new User();

        if (Array.IndexOf(
            new string[] { "Administrator", "Staff", "Student" },
            Contains(GetUserType(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text).Equals(true),
            >= 0))
        {
            Enrollment enroll = new Enrollment();
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Log In", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            enroll.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            txtUsername.Clear();
            txtPassword.Clear();
            txtUsername.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, it will be more obvious what broke it when it breaks.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Pro & SQL 2005. ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrubg and some other that did not exist on my visual studio.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2008, then you are probably developing for the 2.0 runtime, right? Than you can use the Configuration manager as [the documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms254494(v=vs.80).aspx). You're probably missing the a `using System.Configuration` directive or referencing the `system.configuration.dll` assembly. What else didn't you find?

Comment: .NET 3.5SP1 (for which you should be using Visual Studio 2008 SP1) is an upgrade to .NET 2.0. If it's in 2.0, it's in 3.5SP1.